# C++11: How to initialize a private static const member?

Tags: c++11, static, initialization, private, member

Look at this demo code:

```
enum class Solid {gold, silver, wood};
enum class Liquid {bier, wine, oil};
enum class Gas {air, elio, argon};

class P {
private :
    struct Set {
        Solid   solid;
        Liquid  liquid;
        Gas     gas;
    };
    static const Set set[];
};

const P::set = {
        {gold, wine, air}
};
```

GCG tell me:

```
error: ‘const P::Set P::set []’ is private within this context
 const P::set = {
          ^~~
```

What's wrong?
Yes, I would like initialize a static private class member not in the class definition.

Does anyone can explain me the how to do that?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You have a bunch of issues in your code:

- you didn't specify the type of `P::set` in its definition
- you used `enum class`, but didn't quality the enum values (`gold`, etc)

Answer (score 0):

This code is working as intended :

```
enum class Solid {gold, silver, wook};
enum class Liquid{bier, wine, oil};
enum class Gas{air, elio, argon};

class P {
private:
    struct Set {
        Solid solid;
        Liquid liquid;
        Gas gas;
    };
    static const Set set[];
};

const P::Set P::set[]{ Solid::gold, Liquid::wine, Gas::air };
```

You forgot the type identifier `P::Set` in the initialization as well as the class identifiers of the enums.